# Regarding Sharepoint Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have created a sharepoint custom List. When clicking on it displays all the data stored in the site.

I want this list visible to the Administrators.

But I do not want this to visible to the Read only user of the sharepoint site.

I have tried to use audience settings. But on Custom List created I cannot have any option to target a group of user or any user.

Could any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to List Settings > Permissions for this list and select Actions > Edit Permissions. You can then remove the users and groups that should not have access to this list.